# Auto expanding borders, div, page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a square centered page at min. 600px height. The page should expand together with the text. (Ofc.)
The page also have some picture based borders, which should follow the page. (Obviously.)

I've tried a million combinations by now, I think. The problem seems to be that the div-borders cannot auto adjust if the outer div doesn't have a fixed height. And the outer div cannot have a fixed height, due to expanding text.

It seems simple enough. And there're a lot of suggestions. (That doesn't work.) Have I done something fundamentally wrong?

Here's the page: http://bymosegaard-hillerod.dk/info.aspx
(Notice that the borders doesn't reach the bottom.)

For future reference. Here's the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head> 
        <title>...</title> 
        <link href="..." rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">      
    </head> 
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="topborder"></div>
        <div id="leftborder"></div>
        <div id="page">
            <div id="pageheadtext">...</div>
            <div style="float: right; margin-top: 30px;"><img src="/media/banner.jpg"></div>
            <div id="menubar" style="margin-top: 210px;">
                ...
            </div>
            <div id="sideNavigation"></div>
            <div id="bodyText" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightborder"></div>
        <div id="bottomborder"></div>
        <div id="footer">...</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the stylesheet:

```
BODY
{
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 243); 
    background-image: url(/media/bodyBg.gif); 
    background-repeat: repeat-x; 
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102); 
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 10px; 
    height: 95%;
}

H1
{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight:normal; 
}

#pageheadtext
{
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: left;
}

#container
{
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto; 
    width: 786px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 600px;
}

#topborder
{
    background-image: url(/media/frameTopBg.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    display: block; 
    height: 8px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
    margin-left: 0px; 
    margin-right: 0px; 
    margin-top: 0px; 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: hidden; 
    width: 100%;
}

#leftborder
{
    float: left; 
    background-image: url(/media/frameLeftMiddleBg.png); 
    background-repeat: repeat-y; 
    width: 13px;
    min-height: 600px;
    height: auto;
}

#page
{
    background-color: white; 
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin-left: 0px; 
    text-align: left; 
    width: 760px;
}

#rightborder
{
    float: right; 
    background-image: url(/media/frameRightMiddleBg.png);   
    background-repeat: repeat-y; 
    width: 13px;
    min-height: 600px;
    height: 100%;
}

#bottomborder
{
    background-image: url(/media/frameBottomBg.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    clear: both; 
    display: block; 
    height: 13px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
    margin-left: 0px; 
    margin-right: 0px; 
    margin-top: 0px; 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: hidden; 
    width: 100%;
}

#menubar
{
    background-image: url(/media/menubar.jpg);  
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    display: block; 
    height: 27px; 
    width: 760px;
}

#topmenuitem
{
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    cursor: auto;
    line-height: 24px;
    outline-color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    outline-style: none;
    outline-width: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#sideNavigation
{
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-top: 32px;
}

#bodyText
{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 194px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
}

#footer
{
    text-align: center;
}

#doctable
{
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Btw, the page is CMS driven, so I cannot just hack the one offending page. And I would really like to solve this in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **CSS** is over complicated, the **HTML** structure also, not to talk that the design is oldish and the font is hardly readable. And over all that you spiced it using inline styles... This will only lead to to fix a fix of a fix, and not to answer a client call to do just a simple edit / modification.
Hardly maintainable.  **Keep it simple.**

Believe it or not this is all you need:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/qowoyi/2/edit)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My page</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="container"> 
      <h1>Bymosegård i Hillerød</h1>
      <img src="http://bymosegaard-hillerod.dk/media/banner.jpg">

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Forside</a></li> 
          <li><a href="">Info</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Regnskaber</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Referater</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <div id="content">
        <h2>Foretningsorden, relementer mm.</h2>
        <p>Foretningsorden, relementer, vedtægter mm.</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <h3>Vedtægter</h3>
        ................. etc
      </div>
    </div>       
    <div id="footer">Bymosegårds Alle 3-9, 3400 Hillerød</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{ margin:0; padding:0; } /* Global reset */
body{
  background:#EEEDE4;
  font: 10px/1.4 Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; 
  color: #666;
}
h1, h2, h3, p, ul, ol{
  margin: 7px 30px;
  font-weight:200;
}
h1{
  color:#333;
  font-size:1.5em;
  padding:25px 0
}
ul, ol  { padding-left:1.4em; }
nav     { background: #E9E9E9; }
nav li  { display:inline-block; }
nav li a{ display:inline-block; padding:5px 15px; }
#container > img{ width:100%; }
#container{
  position:relative;
  margin: 15px auto;
  width: 786px;
  background: #fff;
  padding:10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#content{ margin:30px 100px; }
#footer{ text-align:center; }
```

Comment: Auch, I suck. ^^ Thanks.